# tkinter typing on an entry box without having to click on the entry first

Tags: python, tkinter

When i open up my tkinter program, I always have to click on the entry box before i can type, is there any way to make it so it lets me type without me having to click on the entry box? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

If you have your entry:

```
myEntry = Entry(root)
```

You only have to add:

```
myEntry.focus_set()
```

This will put the focus on the Entry so you can type immediately without having to click on it.